# "Fatal scripting error" when parsing SQLCMD query

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

*Similar issue seen [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223664/sql-command-mode-unable-to-run-command).*

I am trying to run the following command from SSMS running in SQLCMD mode.

```
:r C:\dev\test scripts\sample.sql
```

But I get the following error:

```
A fatal scripting error occurred.
Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing :r .
```

I have checked the file, the line endings are appropriate for the Windows machine, and the batch separator matches the settings. What else can I try to run this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by changing the file name so that it does not include a space:

```
:r C:\dev\test-scripts\sample.sql
```

Comment: Rather than change the file name, you can enclose the path in double-quotes: `:r "C:\dev\test scripts\sample.sql"`